# SSO in Azure AD with OIDC

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

How to set SSO on Azure AD, please?

As you see my app uses OIDC-based Sign-on. I tried to look after what are the steps to turn on SSO in my app but I found just SAML based SSO.

What do I need to set in Azure AD portal because in the App registration I set everything, please? My app is a hosted Blazor WASM application.

[image]

Comment: could you pls share the tutorial you followed to integrate AAD into your blazor wasm?

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, SSO is enabled by default. You might follow this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to integrate AAD authentication into your Blazor WASM app(or [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for blazor WASM asp.net core hosted app).

In the tutorial, you only need to create the app using the template and modify the property values in appsettings.json.

[image]

Then when we launch the app, we will see the login option in the top-right corner. Since the app didn't set must sign in first to visit the index page, so we won't see it already signs in even we have used one account to sign in azure portal in the same browser. But when we click the sign in button, it won't let us to sign in, it would pop up a window then the sign in process is automatically done. Just like you know when running the app in VS, it would pop up a stand alone browser window, but I test in the same browser window which opened Azure portal, that would work. A different window won't work.

[image]

Comment: Pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement. Thank you for your kind response in advance : )

Comment: Hi Tiny, My application is working in VS 2022 .NET 6 but on an IIS server always returns with this error: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.

Comment: continued... I thought something is incorrect in Azure AD setups but everything is the same like in the dev solution except IDs, URLs. My boss wants a simple SSO: when the user opens the site, the site logs him in unnoticed. Thanks for dealing with my problem.

Comment: I think this could be inplemented automatically --> when the user opens the site, the site logs him in unnoticed.  And about the error message, as you said that's another issue which related to IIS deployment....

Comment: I think so but other said I have to call AzureAD from Blazor WASM gy JS befor index page would be displayed. I think like you it wouldn't be so complocated. I'll try it on a different way next week. Thanks.

Comment: Do you think adding `@page "/" @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization; @attribute [Authorize]` code like this could be a workaround for you? I mean we might adding authentication for the home page, so that whenever we visit the homepage, it would redirect to authentication, if SSO can be used now, it would redirect to Azure sign in page then automatically redirect back along with the signed-in user information.

Comment: I did it: \@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
\@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
\@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "stock")] in my Index.razor. Now I try to install on another server maye it can be a network issue.

Comment: thank you for your reply and let's wait for the test result.